# Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type method group and int

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, datagridview

What is the proper way of doing this

```
     private void grid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.Equals >= (740))
            {
                grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
```

Comment: tried this now im getting no overload for method 'Equals' takes 0 Arguments

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check the `Value`. `Equals()` is a method to check equality.

```
private void grid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value >= 740)
        {
            grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: this is giving me this error.. operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type 'object and int'

Comment: What is the object stored in that cell? If it's an `int` you can use `if ((int)grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value >= 740)`. If it's a `string`, you could try `if (int.Parse((string)grid1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value) >= 740)`.